# Eclipse warning about NullPointer Access - Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to retrieve the UID of a Mifare Classic 1k card, and for that I use this code:

```
    private String getUID(){
    MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get((Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
    byte[] data;
    byte[] sevenDigits = null;
    String uid;

    try{
        mfc.connect();
        boolean auth = false;
        auth = mfc.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(0, MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT);

        if(auth){
            data = mfc.readBlock(mfc.sectorToBlock(0));


            for (int i =0; i < 8; i++){
                sevenDigits[i] = data[i];
            }

            return getHexString(sevenDigits);
        } else {
            return "Authenticatie mislukt";
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Eclipse keeps giving me a warning about this line

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    sevenDigits[i] = data[i];
 }
```

, saying that it can only be null at that point... My question is: how do i rewrite this code so that this warning goes away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sevenDigits
```

is defined as null and not modified. You probably need to call

```
sevenDigits = new byte[data.length];
```

before the loop

Answer (score 0):

You declare the sevenDigits[] as null you must initialize this by its size before you used it

```
sevenDigits[] = new byte[size];
```

do not use the static value in iterator for length use the length of array which you want to use in that for loop

```
data = mfc.readBlock(mfc.sectorToBlock(0));

sevenDigits[] = new byte[data.length];

        for (int i =0; i < data.length; i++){
            sevenDigits[i] = data[i];
        }
```